# having pause/resume button on jpanel form java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to have one Button for pause and resume game background music on Jpanel form, what I have done below is just resets/repeats the sound from the beginning rather than pause and play. and I have look at few other examples here and tried to implement, same thing happened. or just paused it.   any idea what to add to it to make it function?  thanks

```
Boolean isPaused = false;
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      if (isPaused = false ) {
          Game.gameMusic.pause();
          isPaused = true;
      }

      else {
          Game.gameMusic.resume();
          isPaused = true;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that will become

```
  Boolean isPaused = false;
  private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!isPaused ) {
      Game.gameMusic.pause();
      jButton6.setText("resume");
    }
    else {
      Game.gameMusic.resume();
      jButton6.setText("pause");
    }
    isPaused = !isPaused;
 }
```

Comment: after every click you will switch the isPaused value to it negation value so for click one is false = !false ==> true;
for click two true =!true ==> false;
then for click three you will get  true

Comment: also you can read this if statement loudly as :
if isnot paused then pause else resume ; which make a lot of sens when reading than saying in deep heart : 
if isPaused equals false then pause else resume.
I use this small tricks to help my self, may be is good for you too

Comment: thanks , anyway i can change the text within the button  from Pause ---> Resume and vise-versa ?? thanks

Comment: here I updated the answer, I suggest you to do some oop tutorial at udemy then do some search on java swing tutorials that would help for your first step at learning, and keep going ...

Comment: Thanks perfect , it works , do i need to leave the text for the button as blank initially?   and what is Udemy ? i am really interested to enhance/improve my java knowledge and eager to learn more. i just need like exercises to practice on. but not sure where to get these. and a tutor to would be even better to correct you when you do mistakes.   thanks for your reply its always appreciated .

Comment: [here is some free tutorials](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=java%20swing&src=sac&kw=java%20sw&price=price-free)  and feel free to join  [me](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011457115432) when i m online

Comment: you have to already set a text in the scene builder, or you do so by code in the constructor after the initComponent method call.

Comment: ah i see thanks for the tutorial , Udemy is computing , programming  website. i will surely make an account and start doing the works i need to do .   and that would be great . But How can i contact you when your online?  as Stackoverflow don't have Private messaging to contact people diretly ?

Comment: Also , the tutorials are just videos , but i think with coding , you don't learn it properly looking at videos and  reading books , Unless you get Exercises to do / to  practice on . but i don't see that website providing any java Exercises to practice on for different topics. !!

Comment: @charly at udemy there is more than just video, believe me there is more and more, and for contacting me I did give you my link, check it after the udemy link , the "me" is blue is also a link to my account

Comment: sorry for late reply. i shall be using udemy , and i have found some Exercises to do. i do not have fb account , in fact i dead-activated  my account for years now. do you have an e mail or something.

Comment: yes my email talcorpdz@gmail.com I ll help you with pleasure

Answer (score 2):

`if (isPaused = false ) {` is an assignment, not an evaluation, you should be using `==`

Comment: oh wow how did i even forget that  :)  shame on me lol , and i also have to change the second else to false to make it work. so it should be like this :      if (isPaused == false ) {
            Game.gameMusic.pause();
            isPaused = true;
        }

        else {
            Game.gameMusic.resume();
            isPaused = false;
        }

    }

Comment: No, something like `if (isPaused) { } else { }` would be sufficient, let's face facts, it's `true` or it's not

Comment: yes that is another way of doing it . But the feeling that you get when you stare at the code for over Half an hour and you don't realise your using assignment operator rather than equality. i need to pay attention more.  thanks for correcting me. highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees ;)